# We really need both [mingw64] and [mingw-w64]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[mingw64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw64) → [mingw-w64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw-w64)

They both refers to MinGW-W64, and are exactly identical. Even their tag wikis are highly similar, so...

Shall we merge [mingw64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw64) into [mingw-w64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw-w64)? The latter has more question tagged so it's a better merge destination.